# Resolving triggers arising during a move action

Tags: dnd-4e, monk, triggered-actions

I recently designed a Centered Breath Monk, lvl16 that, according to the current build, has an event that triggers when I am missed by a melee attack:

> Ghostwalker, Of Two Worlds (11th level) feature: You have concealment
>   against any enemy granting combat advantage to you. In addition, when
>   any enemy misses you with a melee attack while you have concealment or
>   total concealment, you can shift 1 square as a free action.

QUESTION: How do you resolve this feature triggering during a move action when an enemy granting you CA misses you with an opportunity attack?

Example:

> Monk (speed 10) walks past an enemy on the fifth square of a move action,  provoking an attack of opportunity from an enemy granting me CA. The attack misses.

How does the feature, Of two worlds, interact with my partially completed move action?
I believe that I would be able to immediately shift (after the miss), then continue to finish the move action, since he did not interrupt the action with the miss. This would lead to an effect move of 11 squares for that turn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a character in the middle of a move action alter his movement based on a change in his surroundings?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5245/can-a-character-in-the-middle-of-a-move-action-alter-his-movement-based-on-a-cha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.

The free action movement comes immediately after the attack misses, but before the movement resumes, allowing you to move an additional square.

[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/5257/1084) answer has a lot more information on how the resumption of movement works.